# How to apply JS to user added rows in tabel

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using rails to generate a form that allows the user to click a button to add a new row to a table. As of right now, the user can click the add button and a new row appears.

The trouble I'm having is with a column that is using [autoNumeric](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/) to mask percent values. The JS isn't applied to the columns that the user creates dynamically. I'm using classes so I'm confused why the autoNumeric masking isn't being applied to the new rows as the user is adding them. The 'percentage' class is working on other parts of the form.

```
# JS
$(function() {
  $('.percentage').autoNumeric('init', {aSign: '%', pSign: 's'});
});

# the field is set to the proper class
<tr class="fields">
    <td><input class="percentage" placeholder="Equity %" type="text"></td>
</tr>

# link that adds a new row
<a class="add_nested_fields" data-association="business_contacts" data-blueprint-id="business_contacts_fields_blueprint" data-target="#business_contacts" href="javascript:void(0)">Add a field</a>
```

Each row that is added has class="fields" on it. I have tried JS's onClick but didn't get successful results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your JS is run after the page load, the `autoNumeric` is called on all DOM elements present at the moment with `.percent` class.
But when you add a new row, you ll need to call `autoNumeric` on it again.
Eg:

```
    Function addRow(){       $.('.container').append(this.$row);      $.('.percent').autoNumeric();}
Or you can share ur js code so I can help better.

 $.('.add_nested_fields').click(function()$.('.percent').autoNumeric();})
```

Edit: solution found by the questioner @Questifier

```
  $(function() {  $(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function(event){    $('.percentage').autoNumeric('init', {aSign: '%', pSign: 's'});  })});
```

works perfectly. I read more about the gem after you asked me. Copy that code and make it your answer if you would like- thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes. Right. Just call autoNumeric after each row addition. This is the simplest. By the way which gem are you using for row addition?

Comment: Sorry, JS isn't my strong-suit. When you say after each row addition, how do I do that exactly? What triggers autoNumeric? onClick? I'm using nested_form.

Comment: I never thought to look at the gem docs. I just found an event I can use. I used the nested:fieldAdded event and it works just as expected.

Comment: Bind a onClick event on the link that is adding rows.. And call the autoNumeric in callback of that event

Comment: $(function() {
  $(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function(event){
    $('.percentage').autoNumeric('init', {aSign: '%', pSign: 's'});
  })}); works perfectly. I read more about the gem after you asked me. Copy that code and make it your answer if you would like- thank you for the help.

Comment: Thats great. Thanks for the updation.